# Cannot edit or delete data or rows within phppgadmin

Tags: phppgadmin, ubuntu-22.04, postgresql-14

When I try to edit data in phppgadmin, no matter which table or row, I always got following notification '`No unique identifier for this row.`' and nothing is changed/saved.
The user I'm logged in has full privileges on the database and all tables in database have primary keys.
I'm using phppgadmin for many years and I've never had such a problem before. I should mention, this is a fresh installation of Ubuntu.

Does anyone has a clue what happening here and how to solve this issue? Thanks

**EDIT**
Even downgrading postgresql to version 13 didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reported as a problem with PHP 8.1.x. You can install phpPgAdmin 7.14.2-mod from https://github.com/ReimuHakurei/phpPgAdmin which has a patch to fix this problem.

Comment: The problem hasn't been fixed, even 1 year later. I have a fresh installation of the system and same issue is again occuring!

Comment: can somebody find the difference between debian package and repo?