# Cannot edit or delete data or rows within PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

When I try to edit data in phppgadmin, no matter which table or row, I always got the error 'No unique identifier for this row.' and nothing is changed/saved.
The user I'm logged in with has full privileges on the database and all tables in the database have primary keys and unique keys.
I'm using phppgadmin for many years and I've never had such a problem before. I should mention, this is a fresh installation of Ubuntu.

Does anyone have a clue what happening here and how to solve this issue? Thanks

The PHP version of my application is 7.4 and phppgadmin version is the last one that cPanel accepts PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Comment: Well Postgres 9.2 being 5 1/2 years past EOL is not helping.  Can you connect with `psql` and edit data?

Comment: Abandon cPanel if its developers abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a problem with phpPgAdmin < 7.14.2 incompatibility with php 8.1 ([see](https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/issues/162#issuecomment-1207414311)).

Switching to php 8.0 helped me solve this problem.

You can also follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786862/12238355).